# For the purposes of form 3299: DECLARATION OF FREE ENTRY OF UNACCOMPANIED ARTICLES, am I Emigrating to the US (on an L1 Visa?)

Tags: united-kingdom, usa, shipping, l1-visa

I'm moving the US on an L1 visa and currently trying to complete the paperwork to ship my personal effects over.

I'm struggling to understand the correct answers for the following section of Form 3299:
[image]

Am I "Emigrating to the U.S." or am I "Visiting the U.S"? On one hand, I plan on  living there for at least 2 years; on the other, my visa has a finite length and I use the 'Visitors' line when I enter the country.

I ask because I don't think I can tick "A. (2)" unless I can also select "Emigrating to the U.S.". (as any Tools / Textbooks I am bringing were purchased outside of the US).